# Can you assign a shortcut for a custom tool you created in P4V

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v

I have recently created a custom tool in Perforce P4V that I can use by right clicking a changelist and executing the tool. However, I would like to assign a shortcut to that tool and it does not appear is the "Shortcuts" section. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible now (eg. Verion 2017.3), You can assign a shortcut in the 'Manage Custom Tools' dialog. Just make sure that the dialog is big enough, otherwise you can't see the Shortcut column next to the Name column, or simply scroll to the left.